# android Spinner requires 2 clicks to work

Tags: java, android-studio

am trying to use a spinner within a fragment to categorize the output of my recycler view

when I call the recycler view function from the onCreateView it works perfectly. however, when I call it from the spinner function, it requires 2 clicks to display.

here is the spinner XML code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/med_spinner"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_med2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_spinner"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:entries="@array/medicine"
    />
```

and here is the fragment:

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_medicine, container, false);

    RecyclerView rv_med = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_medicine);
    db = new UserDB(getActivity());
    med_name = new ArrayList<>();
    med_type = new ArrayList<>();
    med_type2 = new ArrayList<>();





    //spinner declartion
    spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.med_spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.medicine, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    //recycler view adapter and layout manger
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterMedicine(getContext(), med_name, med_type, med_type2);
    rv_med.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    rv_med.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    return view;
}
```

and here is the spinner functions

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
    med_name.clear();
    med_type.clear();
    med_type2.clear();
    cata = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    display(cata);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    cata = "All";
    display(cata);
}
```

here's the display function:

```
void display(String type) {
    db.open();
    Cursor cursor = db.listMedicine();
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "an error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
            if (type.equals("All")){
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        med_name.add(cursor.getString(1));
                        med_type.add(cursor.getString(2));
                        med_type2.add(cursor.getString(3));
                }
            }else{
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    if(cursor.getString(2).equals(type) || cursor.getString(3).equals(type)) {
                        med_name.add(cursor.getString(1));
                        med_type.add(cursor.getString(2));
                        med_type2.add(cursor.getString(3));
                    }


            }
        }
        db.close();
    }
}
```

I've tried to put the spinner functions within a spinner.onItemSelectedListener inside and outside the fragment, I tried to enable and disable focus and focusableTochMode, I also tried to call the recycler view before the spinner in the fragment.

Comment: Show us your `display` code

Comment: @VojinPurić I've added it at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to notify your `RecyclerViewAdapter` that data has changed. Add

```
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

at the end of your `display`.

Comment: I've been stuck on this for 3 hours, so from the deepest part of my heart. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help, leaving upvote on answer would be helpful for me if you don't mind